# NPOI XSSFRichTextString/XSSF Hyperlink Excel with hyperlink for part of text

Tags: c#, .net, npoi, xssf

I want to create a cell in excel where only part of the text is a hyperlink.

Something like this
"Click [here](https://test.com)"

It seems like I can only make the whole cell a hyperlink and not a part of the text in the cell. I don't see an option to do this in XSSFRichText or XSSFHyperlink

Answer (score -1):

def Psat(self, T):
pop= self.getPborder(T)
boolean=int(pop[0])

```
P1=pop[1]
P2=pop[2]
if boolean:
    Pmin = float(min([P1, P2]))
    Pmax = float(max([P1, P2]))
    Tr=T/self.typeMolecule.Tc
    w=0.5*(1+scipy.tanh((10**5)*(Tr-0.6)))
    fi1=0.5*(1-scipy.tanh(8*((Tr**0.4)-1)))
    fi2=0.460*scipy.sqrt(1-(Tr-0.566)**2/(0.434**2)+0.494

    guess = Pmin+(Pmax-Pmin)*((1-w**2)*fi1+(w**2)*fi2)   # error here

    solution = scipy.optimize
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).